# Launching seperate process in java, unable to find .png files

Tags: java, python

I am creating a launcher which launches a game (written in any language) on the click of a button. For example, one of the games I try to launch (minesweeper written in python) is unable to successfully launch and my code produces the following message:

../Games/minesweeper/Minesweeper.py successful launch

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "../Games/minesweeper/Minesweeper.py", line 455, in

```
app = Minesweeper()
```

File "../Games/minesweeper/Minesweeper.py", line 30, in **init**

```
self.loadImages()
```

File "../Games/minesweeper/Minesweeper.py", line 71, in loadImages

```
self.images[1] = PhotoImage(file="1.png")
```

File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/tkinter/**init**.py", line 3425, in **init**

```
Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
```

File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/tkinter/**init**.py", line 3381, in **init**

```
self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
```

_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "1.png": no such file or directory

Process exitValue: 1

I am able to run this game as a standalone, however, as soon as my java code launches the exec. "couldn't open "1.png" is returned. Here's my code for the process creation:

```
public void createProcess(String path)
{
    Process cmd;
    try 
    {
        cmd = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path);
        System.out.println(path + " successful launch");
        InputStream stderr = cmd.getErrorStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(cmd.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        System.out.println("<ERROR>");
        while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        System.out.println("</ERROR>");
        int exitVal = cmd.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Use `ProcessBuilder` and change the start directory to reflect the location of the file you are trying to execute...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use the ProcessBuilder class instead of the Runtime objects, it is reccommended. Second, as @MadProgrammer stated, change your starting directory to the file's location. When you run your java program, the 1.png file is relatively located, and is in your java file's path, when you run it individually, the 1.png file is in your python program's path, which is the correct path.

Comment: Thank you! I should have seen that. Editing the file paths relevant to the java program worked perfectly!